# Applying stroke to path in Illustrator moves the path.

Tags: adobe-illustrator

As in title, when I apply stroke value to a path created with pen tool in Ai CS 5.5, this path is being moved. That doesn't apply to all shapes I made. Is there a setting that needs changing or what. I'm unable to create a proper, precise drawing because of that.

Comment: what do you mean by "this path is being moved?"

Comment: I wanted to attach images but I can't. By "being moved" I mean being moved. Anchor point is moving down the artboard a bit every time I change value of stroke. Relatively, I should say, to other objects, to artboard, to grid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly. It seems you may want to tweak the stroke alignment option a bit. Namely align "stroke to center," "stroke to inside" and "stroke to outside." If you do center align, then you may not notice the shift.

[image: stroke alignment]

Edit: I understand your problem now.

You need to disable "Align to Pixel Grid" in the transform option panel for this path.

Comment: It is aligned to center and it shifts! When aligned to inside or outside it stays still. I noticed that already. But obviously aligning it not to the center is not a real solution here. Rendering stroke should be very basic function and it seems like what's happening here is a "feature" of Illustrator. I'm being sarcastic now. There must be a solution, I 'd like to believe...

Comment: @superego I see. I updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: I noticed one more thing. This is happening only when incrementing stroke value with arrows inside of appearance panel. when I type in the value the path stays in place and everything works as expected. Yet - the strange behaviour described above is a mystery.

Comment: @Jin - thank you. You have solved it! I appreciate it!

Comment: @Jin - could this be made default for every art drawn? I looked though preferences but found nothing.

Comment: Does it have any "negative" side effects to not align to pixel grid ?
The option was doing the trick indeed, just wondering what it means

Answer (score 0):

Ahah! I've figured it out!

I noticed that it only started moving it when going from certain values - so for example from 2px to 1px. So I then had a 1px line and was trying to align it to the centre but it wouldn't... so I realised it must be snapping to the pixel grid. So if you turn off "Snap to Pixel Grid" in the transformation window then the path does not adjust itself to lock to the pixel grid! Ahhh that was REALLY bugging me!

Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: So basically what Jin said in 2011?